# Firebase: Does the auth.uid stay active across page tabs?

Tags: security, session, firebase, token, firebase-security

Tools: Firebase 2.3.1

Problem Type : Setting Security Rules for user currently in a session

Authentication Method: authWithPassword()

I know that currently the user is logged into the app in a browser. **I set up my rules with the expectation that once a user has opened a session they can access all the room data in any tab on that browser.**

**Yet if I try fetching this URL below in a different tab in the same browser..**

https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/rooms.json

..I will get back

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

Which is weird because that URL is working just fine in my program in any tab I open my app or if I refresh the page

For instance this isn't throwing any errors:

```
var firebaseRoomsRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/rooms")//fetch just fine
```

Here is what the rules look like:

```
 {
     "rules": {
         "rooms": {
              ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).exists()",
         }
 }
```

**So my main question: 
Is the error only happening because I'm trying to call the URL json directly like that? Or is my app doing something differently that is giving it permission to access messages?**

A side question:
Firebase is automatically storing "auth" as a token or cookie in my program when I call authWithPassword() successfully right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the error is only happening because you're trying to open the URL directly. When you open that URL directly in your browser, there's no auth data sent unless you [append an `auth` query parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-auth).

`https://myfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com/rooms.json?auth=CREDENTIAL`

When you authenticate within your app, Firebase is automatically storing auth as a token in localStorage **only for the domain hosting that app** so that a returning user will retain their session.